# 2D animation is not rendered as it supposed to

Tags: 2d, javascript, animation

I'm working with Melonjs, i have configured everything to update the character movement and still get this "delayed" rendering of the character.

below is the constructor

```
  // call the constructor
  settings.image='kit.walk';
  settings.spritewidth=56;
  settings.spriteheight=80;

  this.parent(x, y, settings);
  this.alwaysUpdate=true;
  // set the default horizontal & vertical speed (accel vector)
  this.setVelocity(3, 15);
  this.setFriction(0.4,0);
  // set the display to follow our position on both axis
  me.game.viewport.follow(this, me.game.viewport.AXIS.HORIZONTAL);
  this.renderable.addAnimation('walk',[0,1,2])
  this.renderable.setCurrentAnimation('walk');
  this.anchorPoint.set(0.5,1.0);
```

i'm not very familiar with the engine, but it doesn't seem to be a problem with the engine, i think is a configuration problem somewhere.. i tried to look into examples but nothing helped so far.

could it be a problem with the sprite?

[image: delay effect]

Comment: By the image provided it does not look like you are clearing your canvas or viewable area between frames.

Comment: i found the problem, i didn't declare "backgroundcolor" map property in Tiled when i did it changed and rendered correctly

Comment: @GeoPhoenix Can you add that as an answer please, so that this thread gets closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not declaring `backgroundcolor` as map property in Tiled and just leaving transparent background causes this.

Adding `backgroundcolor` with value `#191919` or any other color at `Map->Map Properties` will render correctly the animation.